# Converting a vector<tensorflow::Tensor> to tensor of tensors

Tags: c++, tensorflow, tensor

Let's say I have a vector of image tensors with each image tensor having the dimensions of [frames, height, width, num_channels] and I want to take that vector and convert it to one larger tensor of [num_tracks(size of vector), frames, height, width, num_channels].  What's the easiest way to do this with the [tensorflow::Tensor](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/cc/class/tensorflow/tensor) api?  This is for constructing an input tensor for a graph, and not in the graph execution itself.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new Tensor with desired shape, and just fill it out by iterating for all dims in for loops (to access individual item use `operator()` of Eigen's `TensorMap` which you can get by `tensor<DataType,DIMS>` on `Tensor`):

```
tensorflow::Tensor concat(const std::vector<tensorflow::Tensor>& in){
    int frames = in[0].dim_size(0);
    int height = in[0].dim_size(1);
    int width = in[0].dim_size(2);
    int num_channels = in[0].dim_size(3);
    
    int num_tracks = in.size();
    
    tensorflow::Tensor res(DT_FLOAT,tensorflow::TensorShape{num_tracks,frames,height,width,num_channels});
    auto& resMap = res.tensor<float,5>();
    
    for (int nt = 0; nt < num_tracks; ++nt) {
        auto& inFrame = in[nt];
        auto& inMap = inFrame.tensor<float,4>(); // Eigen's TensorMap which has operator()(Indices...)
        
        for (int f = 0; f < frames; ++f) {
            for (int r = 0; r < height; ++r) {
                for (int c = 0; c < width; ++c) {
                    for (int ch = 0; ch < num_channels; ++ch) {
                        resMap(nt,f,r,c,ch) = inMap(f,r,c,ch);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```